# Change one cell in Access table

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

The code runs in excel vba. I have a table named "EngDepAssignments" in access file with the same name. I am trying to change only one  "cell" in the field column "dbRequestor" based on another column called "dbID". So if dbID equals 30, I want to insert/update the intersection of dbRequestor and dbID @ 30 to a name that I get from the excel file, stored in an array "arrdbDashBoard".

However when I run the code I get "Run-time error'-2147217900 (800040e14)': Syntax error in From clause."

I am also not sure if the last line would actually update the location I want since I was not able to get that far.

(probably unrelated but just to explain, I use varDBRecordset.Close to close the recordset after I did some other operation on the table because otherwise I get error that the table is already open at the line "varDBRecordset.Open strSQL")

Great thanks for any help.

```
strSQL = "SELECT dbRequestor FROM EngDepAssignments WHERE dbID = 30"
varDBRecordset.Close
varDBRecordset.Open strSQL
varDBRecordset.Fields("dbRequestor") = arrdbDashBoard(i, 3)
```

Comment: Don't see anything wrong with SQL syntax. To edit data via recordset, record must first be placed in Edit mode (`varDBRecordset.EditMode` for ADO recordset). If adding new record, `varDBRecordset.AddNew`. Then after field edit, `varDBRecordset.Update`. Post more code - how do you establish connection to Access? How do you populate array? Show sample data as text tables in question.

Comment: Open method also needs connection argument parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this is strange. I tried to make it work for last three days. Now when I posted the question, I thought of the fix within few minutes:

```
varDBFilePath.Execute "UPDATE EngDepAssignments SET dbRequestor = " & "'" & arrdbDashBoard(i, 3) & "'" & " WHERE dbID = " & arrdbDashBoard(i, 1)
```